# Next.js error adding "sizes" on Image using layout="responsive"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

Using this code:

```
  <Image
    src="/images/lorem.jpg"
    height={150} 
    width={850} 
    layout="responsive"
    sizes="50vw" // <==  Commenting this line it works
    alt="Lorem ipsum"
  />
```

returns this error

```
TypeError: sizes.matchAll(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

[image]

Without `_document.js`:

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error. Can you reproduce this in a sandbox or a minimal codebase repo?

Comment: Hi @AjeetShah I updated the post with the image. I points to pages/_document.js but the <Image> is in a standard page.

Comment: I tried extending a component like you did in question but I see no errors.

Comment: @FredK What does your image optimization config look like in your `next.config.js`?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves I've no next.config.js, it's just the Next.js example blog https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup

Answer (score 3):

It happens due to wrong configuration the next.config.js

Make sure it looks like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images:{
    domains:['images.unsplash.com']
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```